# library for text classification in java

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, svm

I have a set of categorized text files. I want to categorize another large set of text files to use in my research. Is there a good way to compare them?

I think SVM based methods are useful but is there a simple and documented library for using such algorithms?

Comment: [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) has SVMs, as well as other classification algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about SVM, but [LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/classify/read-me.html) might be really helpful for you. The [link](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/classify/read-me.html) is a tutorial specifically about categorization of documents (automatic or guided).

Also, look into the inter-related search products Lucene (a search library), Solr (search server app), and Carrot2 (for 'clustering' search results). There should be some interesting work in that space for you.

Answer (score 0):

[Mallet](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/) is another awesome library to look into. It has good commandline tools to help you get started and a Java API once you start getting into integrating it with the rest of your system.